# double slit experiment with one-photon per trajectory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Suppose that we have a light emission apparatus capable of emitting only one photon. Then we set this photon to pass in a double slit apparatus and emerge in a black screen such that when it is absorbed the photon lives a mark.

**My question is:** if we close one of the slits, and set a sufficiently large amount of photons perform the above apparatus what we will see in the screen is a normal distribution or a interference pattern? If we set light, instead of photons, we see an interference pattern, correct? But does the one-photon change, changes the way that the experiments shows itself, showing a more 'particle' than 'wave' characteristic of light?

Comment: When you close one of the slits, you cease to have a double-slit experiment.  You now have a single-slit experiment where light only has one possible path, so you will not see interference patterns, whether you use one photon or many.

Comment: @CortAmmon What about the single-slit interference pattern?

Comment: @BillN As in diffraction?

Comment: The experiment you describe is easily repeated.  Google for "one photon at a time".

Comment: A single slit will produce a sinc pattern on the screen

Comment: @JohnRennie, A single slit has two edges.

Comment: @CortAmmon Yes, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html

Comment: The pattern in your link will reppeat even if we have one-photon per a time @BillN?

Comment: I'm trying to suppose what would happen if we say 'the photons passes in one slit or the other, exclusively', i.e, what happens if we consider that the photon goes in one slit only when we make a Young experiment one-photon per time.

Comment: Just like the double-slit single-photon would occur. The edges affect the paths.  In fact, with the double slit you have a pattern developing that's related to both the double-slit spacing *and* the individual slit widths.

Comment: We can't say "I know which slit it went through" without actually measuring it and destroying the interference pattern.

Comment: @BillN that is what I'm trying to show. But the above reasoning imply that if I block one of the slits I'll not destroy the interference pattern correct?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Quantum Eraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment) and its big brother, the [Delayed Choice Quantum Eraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_choice_quantum_eraser).  I don't know if those are *quite* the question you are asking, but they dig into really similar things which might provide an answer to your question.  I'm quite confident the delayed choice quantum eraser will include the answer to your question, but it may be *way* more detail than you need to arrive at your answer.  It's kinda freaky.

Comment: @RafaelWagner, What Cort Ammon said: If you block one of the slits, then it's not a double-slit apparatus.  It's a single-slit apparatus, and if you send enough photons through, they will build up the single-slit diffraction pattern, not the double-slit pattern.

Comment: @RafaelWagner The double slit pattern is **not** the sum of the single slit patterns.  It's a different animal but with an influence from the width(s) of the individual slits.  The double slit produces a fine-spacing of max and min. The widths produce a broader modulation of the fine spacing intensities.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/Single_slit_and_double_slit2.jpg/350px-Single_slit_and_double_slit2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First off - what you describe is a single-slit experiment, not a double-slit experiment. As soon as you know which slit the photons go through, it is no longer a double-slit experiment.

Back to your question. You make a difference between 'light' and 'photons'. I assume that by light you refer to a description in the 'wave-picture'. Note that single photons are also light. The light source simply has a very low intensity. As a consequence - even if you send your photons through the slit one at a time: The outcome will be the same as with what you called 'light'. You simply have to send many photons through the slit.